# react i cant print the first element that is fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to print the description of marbel, so I fetch the marbel and took the first element and put it in marbeldescription and when but when I tried to print it on my website it doesn't show up.

if I `console.log(marbeldescription)` it works properly in console,
any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
const SectionOne = () => {
  const [marbels, setMarbels] = useState([]);
  const [marbeldescription, setMarbelDescription] = useState({});


  useEffect(() => {
    client.fetch('*[_type == "marbels"]').then((data) => {
      setMarbels(data);
    });
  }, []);



  useEffect(() => {
    client.fetch('*[_type == "marbeldescription"]').then((data2) => {
      setMarbelDescription(data2)[0];
    });
  }, []);
  

  return (
    <div className="bg-dark">
      <section className="steps container-custom">
        <div className="row ">
        <Slider {...settings}>
        {marbels.map((marbel, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="col-12 col-sm-6 d-md-flex justify-content-md-ceneter">
          <div>
            <img
              src={urlFor(marbel.imgUrl)}
              alt="Coffe Flavour"
            />
            <p className="text-white">{marbel.name}</p>
          </div>
          </div>
             ))}
          </Slider>
          <div className="col-12 col-sm-6 align-self-center justify-content-md-ceneter text-white">
            <div className="steps__content-width">


              <h1 className="h2 mb-4">Our Marbles</h1>
              
              <p className="mb-4">
              <ul>
                <li style={{color: "white"}}>{marbeldescription.price}</li>
              </ul>
              </p>
              
             
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SectionOne;
```

Comment: Should `setMarbelDescription(data2)[0]`  be  `setMarbelDescription(data2[0])`? It does not seem to be nested, so it could be a typo perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

need to access the first property of the array. not the setState

```
  setMarbelDescription(data2[0]);
```